# WHERE in groceryCRUD

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

I have problem and I am requesting for your help.

I am trying to use WHERE depending on user inputs; I would like if there is no user inputs system should take default settings from the db but if there is user inputs the system should use it; I have the following codes but do not work! Please help me; thanks.

```
public function show_list()
    {
        //Page title
        $data['page_title'] = 'Users List';
        if( $this->require_min_level(1) ){
        //if there is inputs data for custom selection do this
        $testdate1=$this->input->post('start_date');
        $testdate2=$this->input->post('end_date');
        if($testdate1=="" && $testdate2=="")
                {
                // this load system data in order to use it in querying the db
                        $system_data=$this->system_data_model->load_system_data();

                        foreach ($system_data->result() as $sdata){
                        $data['financial_year_start'] = $sdata->financial_year_start;
                        $data['financial_year_end'] = $sdata->financial_year_end;
                        }               
                }
                //if there is inputs data for custom selection do this
                else{

        $data = array(
                'financial_year_start' => $this->input->post('start_date'),
                'financial_year_end' => $this->input->post('end_date'),
                'custom_financial_year_end'=>$this->input->post('end_date'),
                );

                }
        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
        $crud->where('employed_date>=', $data['financial_year_start']);
        $crud->where('employed_date<=', $data['financial_year_end']);
        $crud->set_table('users');  
        $crud->columns('user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name','gender','user_name','mobile_number','user_email','company_division','job_position', 'office_location', 'employed_date');
        $crud->fields('user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name','gender','user_name','mobile_number','user_email','company_division','job_position', 'office_location', 'employed_date');
         // edit how column data is displayed
        $crud->display_as('company_division','Division');
        $crud->display_as('job_position','Position');
        $crud->display_as('employed_date', 'Employed');

        //prevent unwanted operations
        $crud->unset_read();
        $crud->unset_add();
        $crud->unset_delete();
        $crud->unset_edit();
        //render data
        $output = $crud->render();
 //call aotput function
        $this->_users_list_output($data, $output);         
    }
    }

    function _users_list_output($data, $output = null)
    {
 if( $this->require_min_level(1) ){

         //load view
        $this->load->view('includes/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('includes/reports_menu');
        $this->load->view('list_users_view',$output);
        $this->load->view('includes/footer');
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function show_list()
{
     $data = array(
      'list_item' => $this->input->post('name')
     );

     if($this->input->post('name') == ""){//assuming empty is passed, you can also check to see if it's set
            $this->db->where('default_settings');
      }else{
            $this->db->where('name', $this->input->post('name');
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks; but may you provide example related with my codes; and some sort of explanations please; thanks